# How to test calls that are wrapped in a setImmediate in jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I have business logic wrapped in a setImmediate like so:

```
// business logic
export async function myFunc() {

    setImmediate(() => {
        myModule.doStuff();
    });
}
```

I want to make expectations on the myModule.doStuff() call. However I can't because the test code is on the call stack before the setImmediate gets executed. How can I put expectations on code that are wrapped in a setImmediate?

Answer (score 1):

Since [setImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) is a Non-standard method, jasmine does not support mock its clock.

> This method can be used instead of the setTimeout(fn, 0) method to execute heavy operations.

Therefore, you can use `setTimeout(fn ,0)` to replace it, they are equivalent. Then, you can use [jasmine.clock](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Clock.html) to simulate the clock.

More info, see [issue#866](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/866).